# RobotFramework : Test suite setup - no file found erorr but the file exists

Tags: robotframework

I have the **init**.robot file as below , what this keyword do is start Servers listening on ports before the tests start and teardown once all the tests are run.Have been struggling to get this right for long time

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  A sample  test sutie for  Transaction
Library  Process

Suite Setup   init


****** keywords ***

init


    log  '${CURDIR}'

    ${result} =    Run Process    python ${CURDIR}/StartServer.py
    log  '${result.stdout}'
    Should Not Contain    ${result.stdout}    FAIL
```

my StartServer.py file is , if i run the file in the system with python StartServer.py the file runs

```
import sys,os
import threading
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '../..'))
sys.path.append(path)

from keywordslib.MadaTransactionLibrary import MadaTransactionLibrary


madatransactionlibrary = MadaTransactionLibrary()
print('hello')
madatransactionlibrary.connectServers()
```

when i run tests I get the below error, although the file exists in the location

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Madatransactions.SamplePurchase :: A sample test sutie for Mada Tr... | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python /home/rsc_app/rscatddframework/src/testsuites/madatransactions/StartServer.py': 'python /home/rsc_app/rscatddframework/src/testsuites/madatransactions/StartServer.py'

1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

any help is appreciated ,not sure it is considering python as program or as directory

Solved Solution

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  A sample  test sutie for  Transaction
Library  Process

Suite Setup   initserver
Suite Teardown  Terminate All Processes     kill=True


****** keywords ***

init


    log  '${CURDIR}'

    ${result} =    Start Process    python3      ${CURDIR}/StartServer.py     stdout=${CURDIR}/logout.txt    stderr=${CURDIR}/err.txt
    log  '${result.stdout} ${result.stderr}'

initserver
    Start Process    python3      ${CURDIR}/StartServer.py
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the error carefully. It is literally looking for a file with the name  `python /home/rsc_app/rscatddframework/src/testsuites/madatransactions/StartServer.py`. What is the “solved solution” part of the question? Do you still need help? If not, consider deleting the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley the solution is to use python3 instead of python. even though env is configured with alias python = python3 . in this scenario we have to explicitly mention python3 ( for which robot framework is installed)

Comment: alias loading is a shell feature and aliases are usually set up in "login" scripts. run process by default doesnt spawn a new shell, so aliases are not loaded automatically.

Comment: but also, what @BryanOakley said is still valid, you did not have proper argument separator in the command so "run process" keyword was looking for a *file* bryan highlighted  and obviously failing.